# Сертификат SSL от letsencrypt только без www

Tags: ssl, letsencrypt

Я сделал сертификат от letsencrypt
Как оказалось я домен без www указал и теперь www.site.ru открывается с предупреждением безопасности.

Как перевыпустить SSL сертификат от letsencrypt в таком случае?

Comment: вы уверены, что этого имени нет в сертификате? проверьте: `$ openssl x509 -in /путь/к/файлу/с/сертификатом -noout -text | grep DNS`

Comment: cd letsencrypt/linter_plugin.py ^C
root@rai-sad:/# openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/rai-sad.ru-0001/ -noout -text | grep DNS
unable to load certificate
140702028932776:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Comment: вы указали путь к каталогу, а надо к файлу (с сертификатом).

Comment: DNS:rai-sad.ru (как я понимаю это значит - нет)

Comment: т.е., всё-таки `www.bla.bla` отсутствует? ну, значит надо перевыпускать сертификат. сохраните (на всякий пожарный) полученные файлы в какое-нибудь другое место и повторите запрос, указав правильные параметры. будьте внимательнее — letsencrypt накладывает некоторые [rate-limits](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/).